# Whether a set of vectors span a subspace that includes a given vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Do the vectors $(0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 1), ( -1, 2, 4)$
>
> a) span $\mathbb R^{3}$
>
> b) span a subspace that includes $w = (-2, 2, 10)$

I know they don't span $\mathbb R^3$ since they are linearly dependent. I know $\mathbb R^3$ itself is a subspace that includes $w = (-2, 2, 10)$. But there must be a better explanation for $b$ which I don't know how to do.

Comment: 4 vectors spanning $R^3$ will be linearly independent.

Comment: Your vectors do span $\Bbb R^3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the three vectors you give **do** span $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, because they are linearly **independent**. And since they span the entire $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, then every vector in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, including $\mathbf{w}$ belongs to their span.

But lets take a look on how you would handle a problem like that:
You are given three vectors $\mathbf{v}_{1}$, $\mathbf{v}_{2}$ and $\mathbf{v}_{3}$. 
What does it mean *"$\mathbf{w}$ belongs in the subspace spanned by these three vectors"*?
It means that $\mathbf{w}$ can be written as a linear combination of these vectors,
or equivalently that there exist coefficients $c_{1}$, $c_{2}$ and $c_{3}$, such that
$$
c_{1} \mathbf{v}_{1} +c_{2} \mathbf{v}_{2} + c_{3} \mathbf{v}_{3} = \mathbf{w}.
$$
In matrix form, let $A$ be the matrix obtained by stacking the $\mathbf{v}_{i}$s as columns:
$$
\mathbf{A} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 0 &1 &-1\\
 1 & 2 & 2 \\ 
 2 & 1 & 4
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then, $w$ belongs to the span of the columns of $A$ if and only if there exists vector $c$ such that
$$
\mathbf{A}\mathbf{c} = \mathbf{w}.
$$
In other words, the question of whether $\mathbf{w}$ belongs to the span of $\mathbf{v}_{i}$s is equivalent to: *does the linear system $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{c}= \mathbf{w}$ have a solution?*

**Alternative perspective**:
If $\mathbf{w}$ belongs to the span of $\mathbf{v}_{1}$, $\mathbf{v}_{2}$ and $\mathbf{v}_{3}$,
then as mentioned above, there exist coefficients $c_{1}$, $c_{2}$ and $c_{3}$, such that
$$
c_{1} \mathbf{v}_{1} +c_{2} \mathbf{v}_{2} + c_{3} \mathbf{v}_{3} = \mathbf{w}.
$$
Lets say that you have determined that 
$$
\text{rank}(A) = \text{rank}([\mathbf{v}_{1}\; \mathbf{v}_{2}\; \mathbf{v}_{3}])= r.
$$
If $\mathbf{w}$ belongs to the span of $\mathbf{v}_{i}$s, then the rank of the extended matrix
$\mathbf{B} = [\mathbf{v}_{1}\; \mathbf{v}_{2}\; \mathbf{v}_{3}\;\mathbf{w}]$ should also be equal to $r$, *i.e.*, $\mathbf{w}$ does not add to the rank. If, on the contrary, $\mathbf{w}$ *did not* belong in the span of $\mathbf{v}_{i}$s it would implied that $\mathbf{w}$ has a *component* (part) that lies *outside* the subspace spanned by $\mathbf{v}_{i}$s. In that case, we would have $\text{rank}(\mathbf{B}) > \text{rank}(\mathbf{A})$.

Answer (score 1):

If these vectors (we denote them $u_1,u_2,u_3$) span a subspace that includes $w$ then we find $a,b,c\in\Bbb R$ such that

$$au_1+bu_2+cu_3=w$$